# How to make imageview's background to scale proprtionally in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, scale, geometry

What i need is that image should be scaled till it retains the exact proportions after that it should not be scaled further, so that every time width is equal to height of the image view.

As if don't scale properly it will get out of shape, and i need it to be in 1:1 ratio of width and height.

Will

```
 Imageview:scale="fitxy"
```

work in this case ?

Please help thnk you.

I am working on android ICS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep aspect ratio, you should make the image the `src` rather than `background`.

Take a look at the ScaleType documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html.

You should try using either `android:scaleType="centerInside"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Fits the screen size of the device.

Try this adding this

```
    android:layout_height="150dp" //or your designed proportion
    android:layout_width="150dp" //or your designed proportion
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: This will cause the image to become distorted if it was not originally a square.